# All axios requests stalling on one machine, but not in incognito

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, google-chrome, axios

this question is very specific, but I thought i'd see if any one else has ever experienced this. My app is a React-Redux frontend with a Django Backend. Frontend and backend are hosted on two different EC2 servers.

Only one user has this issue, where the website loads, however every request afterwards is "stalling". the request is still active but it is pending and never completes. the request never makes it to the backend EC2 (checked cloudwatch logs). The user had an adblock installed but disabling it did not fix the issue.

When the user opens a new browser in incognito, the application works fine. Any ideas as to what is going on?

All requests are being made with axios, and the browser in question is Google Chrome.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: `When the user opens a new browser in incognito, the application works fine. Any ideas as to what is going on?` Guess: the user has a chrome extension (not available in incognito) that is probably trying to proxy all requests and the proxy is unresponsive. Ask them to go through their chrome extensions (go to `chrome://extensions/`) and have a looksy

Comment: I understand it could be a different extension other than adBlocker, but how is my site not functioning and other sites are? Is there something I need to add to my axios configuration to allow foreign extensions to proxy my requests? Thanks for the response!

Comment: It's not your responsibility to police every possible chrome extension (or intranet) each one of your users has installed/is using. Is this a single user who is reporting an issue? How many users are using this portal? How many users are experiencing problems? There's nothing you need to change. If you want to help the user find out what's going on, it's because of a chrome extension or intranet or VPN or something like that that is proxying their requests.

Comment: Hm, I see your point and I do agree with you. This is an internal enterprise application for approximately 10 or so users and only one has this problem. I was simply curious as to why this possible extension is proxying specifically the requests for my site, but no other site. I feel like there is something in my code that is awry and something I should include in axios configuration. If that isnt the case I am at a loss